# Can't execute Action.perform() within Maven context

Tags: java, maven, selenium, click, webdriver

I've created a JUnit test with WebDriver. It runs perfectly.
But when I want to execute it in the Maven context (Integration Server), the `perform()` method doesn't work.

This perform is to simulate a 'right click':

```
/**
 * 
 * @param webEl
 *            : WebElement on which you want to click
 * @param nameEl
 *            : String that perfectly matches the name of the option you
 *            want to select
 */
protected void rightClickLink(WebElement webEl, String nameEl) {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);       
    action.contextClick(webEl).build().perform(); // HERE   
    driver.findElement(By.linkText(nameEl)).click();
}
```

When I want to build Maven, all it's alright before the line whith the "HERE" comment.

Question 1 : Why running this test on Maven (server) break this code? 
Question 2 : How can I fix it ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not work' ? Error messages or what?

Comment: The test stop. In fact, all line before THE line seems to be execute correctly, and after, the execution abort. The maven result is : "Results :
Tests in error:   Domaining_msoa005Test.testCreateSD:71->createAndTestSD:414->JIHM.rightClickLink:40 » NoSuchMethod" "  (l40 = Line 'HERE')

Comment: So you are using a wrong method or a wrong version.

Comment: The method is good for JUNIT (run in success), so it's a problem version i think. Is it possible to have a method whose is good for local/Standalone developpement but not for a maven(server) project? (run on JUNIT VS build & test on Maven)

Comment: during the call in your case there is no relation anymore to Maven. You test is the problem using wrong method etc. Withtout the full output of error messages instead of excerpts it's hard to see what the real problem is. Apart from that the pom files are helpful as well.

Comment: humm.. After many test, i don't think the probleme come to the methode. Because **I can use it correctly without maven** and with a local maven project. But i'm not a expert.  *If it's the real probleme (wrong methode), do you know how* can i make a 'rigth click' with WebDriver whithout use perform() ? (to show webElement's options after make click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED !! Ok for people who (maybe) need the answer, be carefull is pretty strange.

I used the **WebConsole** object.
(package Selenium : *import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole;*) to show sentence (like System.out.println()).
And the sentences was printed on the screen.

But if I erase all **WebConsole** opérations, my bug disapear.

So there is a compatibility bug i guess, and it wasn't a problem of wrong code :P